# What is the semantic meaning of the Google search operator "related:domain.TLD" as it relates to SEO?

Tags: seo

**Examples:**

- [http://www.google.com/search?q=related:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=related%3astackexchange.com)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=related:google.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=related%3agoogle.com)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=related:bing.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=related%3abing.com)

If if has no meaning, is there a online tool that will generate a list of related TLDs?

Comment: It doesn't really relate to SEO. It's just a (possibly) useful search tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It doesn't really relate to SEO. It's just a (possibly) useful search tool. – John Conde♦ 2 days ago"

Answer (score 2):

According to [GoogleGuide.com/Similar_Pages](http://www.googleguide.com/similar_pages.html):

> How does Google find similar pages?
>     By finding other sites listed on pages that link to the specified page.  ...  related: search operator, returns the same results as the Similar pages link.

So there is nothing that has anything to do with TLD, and everything that has to do with links that reside with the link to a particular website on the same page.

How you want to relate this to SEO is up to you I guess.

PS: I doubt it is so simplistic as GoogleGuide describe, there are probably more heuristics and criteria used by Google to find similar pages - but we will never know these criteria. (based on their blog post about [discovering similar pages](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/discovering-pages-similar-to-ones-that.html)).

Comment: Good point regarding the TLD, thanks! One thing I find interesting is how few "results" there are, in fact, I haven't found one search yet that produces more than 200 results... :-) ...very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can relate to SEO as in "a list of possible websites I want to get links from", if you check the websites related to your own.